# How to upload a file stored in memory (using Python's tempfile) to S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, temporary-files

I want to upload some video clips to Amazon S3. These videos are generated as intermediate results. So, I prefer to store these small video clips in memory (around 400~500 KB), then upload each of them to S3.

After uploading, the temporary files can be removed from memory. Hence, I want to use `tempfile`. But there are errors in the following code. Please take a look and how to do it correctly?

```py
@contextmanager
def s3upload(key):
    with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=1021*1000) as buffer:
        yield buffer
        buffer.seek(0)
        # key.send_file(buffer)
        k.set_contents_from_file(buffer)
        k.set_acl('public-read')
```

```py
conn = boto.connect_s3()
b = conn.get_bucket('cc_test_s3')
k = Key(b)
k.key = '1.flv'
mime = mimetypes.guess_type('1.flv')[0]

with s3upload(k) as out:
    out.write('1.flv')
```

Output:

> The size of file uploaded is 5 KB, which is much less than the actual size of 1.flv (~400 KB).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use s3fuse , which will basically mount your s3 bucket on your local drive and then you can directly save the files as if you are saving in local directory. for reference you can look at [s3fuse - google-code](http://code.google.com/p/s3fuse/)

Comment: I create a tempfile under /tmp directory. Then write intermediate result to this tempfile. After the file is uploaded, this tempfile is deleted.

Comment: Alright, so in s3fuse , your document will be occupying/ stored on s3 only. you will just get a feel that its like local directory (/tmp). you don't need to delete the tempfile.

Comment: The link is dead.